# Hibernating to swap file on Debian 12 returns "Call to Hibernate failed: Not enough swap space for hibernation"

Tags: debian, hibernate

new Linux desktop user here.

I installed Debian 12 with the default small swap partition, but hibernation didn't work properly, so I followed this guide:

[How to use hibernation without a swap partition.](https://wiki.debian.org/Hibernation/Hibernate_Without_Swap_Partition)

I have 16GB of RAM and created a 24GB swap file and disabled the swap partition, but now the `Hibernate` button dissappeared from KDE's "Application Launcher" and running `sudo systemctl hibernate` returns `Call to Hibernate failed: Not enough swap space for hibernation`.

This is the state of my system:

```
> sudo swapon --show
NAME             TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/home/user/swap file  24G   0B   10

> cat /proc/swaps
Filename                                Type            Size            Used            Priority
/home/user/swap                        file            25165820        0               10

> free -m
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15908        4709        5692         139        5980       11198
Swap:          24575           0       24575


> cat /etc/fstab
#...
/home/user/swap swap swap pri=10 0 0
#...


> ls ~ -l
...
-rw------- 1 root  root  25769803776 Jan 16 19:33 swap
...

> findmnt -no UUID -T /home/user/swap
76e6bab2-1c86-4abe-841e-7ad0a3ba778c

> sudo filefrag -v /home/user/swap|awk 'NR==4{gsub(/\./,"");print $4;}'
62373888

> cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
RESUME=UUID=76e6bab2-1c86-4abe-841e-7ad0a3ba778c resume_offset=62373888

> cat /etc/default/grub
#...
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=76e6bab2-1c86-4abe-841e-7ad0a3ba778c resume_offset=62373888"
#...

> update-grub
> update-initramfs -k all -u
```

I'm trying to configure hibernation since there is some problem when sleeping for more than an hour, probably a PSU issue. Secure boot is disabled.

Comment: From the looks of your `fstab`, you didn't follow the Wiki entry exactly.  For a `fstab` entry,  the line needs to read exactly as the Wiki has it.  Secondly, `/home` has special meaning.  Never put something to be used systemwide in the `/home` directory unless it requires creating a user, which is normally handled by the package manager.  Either start over and follow the Wiki entry to the letter, and delete `/home/user/swap` or resize your partitions as my answer suggests

Comment: I tried with `/home/user/swap swap swap defaults 0 0`. I'll try to put the swap file in the root partition, but it it needs to be resized also, which seems problematic based on their order.

Comment: If it needs to be resized, delete it and just recreate it.  Nothing is ever statically saved to swap.  Use G instead of m.  The other issue you're going to run into with this is that your swap is now non-contiguous, and you're going to lose the small amount of swap you did create (Type 83) when you instruct the kernel to turn on `swapiness`.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the [Debian Hibernation Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Hibernation):

> Suspend and hibernate configuration in Debian Jessie
>
> You may get hibernation working out of the box (even without uswsusp), provided that you have a swap partition big enough to hold an image of the system.

### Standard Practice

1. Linux Swap must be Partition Type 83
2. The Formula for computing swap size that I've always seen is twice the amount of your RAM.

---

I'm assuming your hibernated image will not take up 24GB, but I've never seen anyone attempt to hibernate to a users home directory.  To fix this, I would use a Graphical Partitioning Tool like [GParted](https://gparted.org/), and make room for an actual swap partition by resizing your existing partitions, creating or resizing a partition of type 83 and reassign a new UUID and update `fstab` and GRUB 2.